# "error: process ID list syntax error"

Tags: remote, ps

I have bash a script that logs in to a remote server, and checks for the number of instances of a desired script `script.py` running on that server, and subsequently echoes the total memory consumed by that script on that node, along with some aggregate statistics such as the total memory present and the memory consumed by the all the processes associated with the script. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
for server in servername; do
    ssh $server << EOF
    num_proc=0
    sum_virt=0
    procs=$(pgrep -f script.py)
    if [[ "$procs" ]]; then
        for pid in $(pgrep -f script.py); do
            x=`ps -p $pid -o %cpu,%mem,cmd,vsize`
            virt=`echo $x | cut -d " " -f 9`
            sum_virt=`echo "$virt + $sum_virt" | bc -l`
            let "num_proc++"
        done

        total_mem_cons=`vmstat -n -s | grep "used memory" | awk '{print $1}'`
        tot_mem=`vmstat -n -s | grep "total memory" | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "Total Memory Consumption on node $server: $total_mem_cons"
        echo "Total memory on node $server: $tot_mem"

    else
        echo "No script.py process running on node $server"

    fi
EOF
done
```

However, this is giving me this error:

```
error: process ID list syntax error
Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Also, it seems to be going into the else condition, despite there being processes present when I log into the server manually.

I do not see anything wrong with the script, and I have tried to output the commands individually to see what is going wrong, but can't find the issue. Individually running `ps -p $pid -o %cpu,%mem,cmd,vsize` seems to give me the correct output, which suggests there is something wrong with the loop that loops through the `pid`'s, but I don't really know for sure what could be going wrong.

EDIT: I used the following test code to test the basic functionality and this seems to be returning empty as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
for server in servername; do
    ssh $server << EOF
    num_proc=0
    sum_virt=0
    pgrep -f script.py | while read -r pid ; do
        echo "PID: $pid"
    done            
    total_mem_cons=`vmstat -n -s | grep "used memory" | awk '{print $1}'`
    tot_mem=`vmstat -n -s | grep "total memory" | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "Total Memory Consumption on node $server: $total_mem_cons"
    echo "Total memory on node $server: $tot_mem"

EOF
done
```

i.e all it returns is:

```
PID: 
PID: 
PID: 
Total Memory Consumption on node servname: 
Total memory on node servername:
```

which means that even the memory consumption output is coming out as zero as well. Again testing the commands on the individual server, seems to give out correct results.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the answer. I checked `$procs` on the server, its empty, and separately running `procs=$(pgrep -f script.py)` does yield results as well which should mean that `ps` shouldn't technically run with nothing. Do you think there is anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: I edited my code as well, to check the basic results (added the script in the original post), and it seems to again come out empty.

Comment: And if you change that to `echo "PID: \$pid"` (or change `<< EOF` to `<< 'EOF'` to prevent any expansion)?

Comment: @steeldriver Changing `<< EOF to << 'EOF'` solves it! I'll read up more on expansion, does that prevent the shell from reusing existing assignments? (I am very new to bash). Also, if you could add this as an answer, I could put it down as an accepted answer! Thanks so much! I've spent hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in `man bash` (note that your `/bin/sh` may be something other than bash, but the same applies to other Bourne-like shells):

> ```
>    The format of here-documents is:
>
>           <<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
>
>    No  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>    expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any  charac‐
>    ters  in  word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal
>    on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If  word
>    is  unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>    expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  charac‐
>    ter  sequence  \<newline>  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the
>    characters \, $, and `.
> ```

The key part here for understanding your case is

> If  word is  unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion

meaning that things like `$pid`, `$x` and so on will have their values from the local shell, rather than from the remote SSH session. The error

```
error: process ID list syntax error
```

is consistent with `$pid` being empty in the command substitution `ps -p $pid -o %cpu,%mem,cmd,vsize`

Note that if you'd quoted the variable expansion - which is a good habit to get into

```
ps -p "$pid"  -o %cpu,%mem,cmd,vsize
```

you'd have got a marginally more helpful error `list of process IDs must follow -p`

You can prevent individual variables from being expanded prematurely by backslash escaping them e.g. `\$pid` however in your case, the only thing you want to expand is `$server` - and that's outside the here-document, so you may as well prevent *any* expansion by quoting `word` itself:

```
for server in servername; do
    ssh $server << 'EOF'
    .
    .
EOF
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! I read the `Example 19-7` over [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html]) as well which was helpful too.